# How can I fix this randomly occurring issue with not finding cache file in my Laravel application?

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-5

I randomly get this issue in my application.

```
ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 81:
file_put_contents(/usr/share/nginx/www/my_application/storage/framework/cache/05/da/05da7b09ff2f176f41f594275e03d8fe): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
in Filesystem.php line 81
```

I tried google it but came up with nothing. When I check the server I can find a file there

Answer (score 0):

Delete all of them. It will created automatically when runing app.

Comment: Is that a long term solution?